# ubuntu server 22.04 scrambled screen

Tags: server, graphics

Hello and happy new year,

I have tried to install ubuntu server 22.04 on this mini (fan less) pc, but at one point in the installer (I believe after the keyboard key map selection), the screen was scrambled, making the rest of the installation impossible. I got the same result with 20.04. I was able however to install version 18.04 without any issues. I thought the problem was with the installer, so I went ahead and did the release upgrade to 20.04, but after the reboot, the screen was scrambled and I could not even ssh into the server from another machine. I have now reinstalled the 18.04 version, but I would like to keep the OS current if possible. Here is the info on the machine:

Processor:Intel Core i7 6500u
Video: Intel HD Graphics 520

I am a bit perplexed as to why the video would have issues on an operating system that does not have a graphical user interface.

Your help ion this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "scrambled"?

Comment: Basically that the whole screen is illegible. There are lines across the screen of different colors. The lines are also moving around on the screen.